# How to implement image processing on virtual reality videos with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, virtual-reality

I started with OPENCV js tutorials yesterday.Now i can do my basic editing and image-processing operations on 2D videos but How can i do this editing and image -processing operations in VR videos?I am looking for javascript library that can do editing and image-processing operations on my mono 2D 360 footage VR videos.How can i get started?

Comment: What image processing operations do you want to do? What VR format do you want to do them to? Stereoscopic footage? 2D 360 footage? Please be more specific.

Comment: thank you.I am looking for 2D 360 fooatage approach.Stereoscopic footage is look like very hard stuff  to program because stereoscopic footage has different polarization for each sides.

Comment: So a video source that looks something like this then: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rocketstockassets/uploads/ready-2-equi.png  And what do you want to do with it?

Comment: i want  to extract the moving foreground from static background

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to do anything differently than you would on standard footage. There is actually a SO category that contains methods for doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background-subtraction

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the best way to convert 2D 360 footage VR video to 2D image frames?i want to process 360 Monoscopic Videos from internet (youtube,dailymotion...) using an url frame by frame.How to get 2D frames from given URL?

Comment: Most video hosting websites don't have readily available/sanctioned API's that allow you to download the MP4 files (they make money by having you go to their website to watch the video alongside ads after all).

There are various sites/plugins, etc that allow you to download videos from these websites, but they're meant to be used in a one-off fashion.

Comment: ACVM is correct. To answer your other question, you don't need to convert from 360 video to 2D video. It is still stored in normal 2D video files like mp4, etc. The video file will just be warped like the image I posted above.

Comment: Thank you all.How to do image processing on these videos without downloading  them?i can'I store all the stream in desktop.